# Zoom an image in a picture box

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, paint, picturebox

I know there are many discussion this topic already but still i could not find an answer. Hope someone have a idea.

I load a bitmap in a `PictureBox` (`SizeMode` Normal, `DockStyle` Fill) and use the `Paint` event to draw the image.

To zoom I use `MouseWheel` event and increase / decrease zoom factor (Like _zoomFac += 1). The goal is to zoom at the mouse position. So in the `MouseWheel` event I also save the mouse position (`_imageZoomLocation`). This is my code (only little test implementation):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private Image _image;
  private float _zoomFac;
  private PointF _imageZoomLocation;

  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    _image = null;
    _zoomFac = 1F;
    _imageZoomLocation = PointF.Empty;
    pictureBox.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseWheel);
  }

  private void pb_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
    if (_image == null)
      return;
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-_imageZoomLocation.X +    _imageZoomLocation.X / _zoomFac, -_imageZoomLocation.Y +   _imageZoomLocation.Y / _zoomFac);
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(_zoomFac, _zoomFac, MatrixOrder.Append);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, new Point(0,0));
  }

  private void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ... Code for loading image
  }

  private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (_image == null)
      return;

    _imageZoomLocation = e.Location;

    if (e.Delta > 0)
      _zoomFac += 1F;
    else
      if (_zoomFac - 1F < 1F)
        _zoomFac = 1F;
      else
        _zoomFac -= 1F;

    Refresh();
  }

  private void pb_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    pictureBox.Focus();
  }
}
```

This works well as long as `_imageZoomLocation` is not changed, means the mouse is not moved i can zoom in and out perfectly (I can change mouse position when zoom factor is 1 and everything still works). However when I move the mouse to different position in a zoomed state (e.g. zoom factor is 2) and scroll, the image jumpes once to a different position than the mouse is and after this "jump" everything works well again.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: This sounds a lot like it is `winforms` technology.

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot to mentiond.

Comment: Please [don't put tags into the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/130208#130208).

Comment: You will need to either start getting familiar with Visual Studio's awesome debugger, or provide us wit *all* relevant code, which will probably be such a hopeless endeavor, that in all likelihood you will end up getting familiar with Visual Studio's awesome debugger *anyway*.

Comment: Don't worry i use vs since it exists and know how to use a debugger :-). But i will update the code sample like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line, you are dividing imageZoomLocation.X and .Y by the zoom factor only half the time. Instead, maybe you need a separate variable to keep the previous mouse location.

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-_imageZoomLocation.X + _imageZoomLocation.X / _zoomFac, _
                              -_imageZoomLocation.Y + _imageZoomLocation.Y / _zoomFac);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just i saw my mistake. Of course, if i move the mouse in the zoomed image the mouse coordinates will be magnified by the zoom factor :). I think your suggest is a step in the right direction!